# Restricting the class to accept only any one interface implementations but not mixed?

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-7

I have below classes and interfaces.

SuperInterface.java

```
public interface SuperInterface{/*some logic*/}
```

SubOneInterface.java

```
public interface SubOneInterface extends SuperInterface{/*some logic*/}
```

SubTwoInterface.java

```
public interface SubTwoInterface extends SuperInterface{/*some logic*/}
```

One.java

```
public class One{/*some logic*/}
```

Two.java

```
public class Two{/*some logic*/}
```

SubOne.java

```
public class SubOne extends One implements SubOneInterface{/*some logic*/}
```

AnotherSubOne.java

```
public class AnotherSubOne extends One implements SubTwoInterface{/*some logic*/}
```

SubTwo.java

```
public class SubTwo extends Two implements SubOneInterface{/*some logic*/}
```

AnotherSubTwo.java

```
public class AnotherSubTwo extends Two implements SubTwoInterface{/*some logic*/}
```

Now  i have to write a class which will hold the implementation classes of both SubOneInterface and SubTwoInterface.

```
public class ClassesHolder{

 private List<One> one;
private List<Two> two;

//setters and getters

}
```

Now `ClassesHolder` should accept all the objects(**sub classes of One and Two**) which implements either `SubOneInterface` or `SubTwoInterface` But not mix of both interfaces.

IF they try to populate the lists with mixed interface implementations then exception should be thrown.

How can i do that?

Comment: With the generic names above, it's hard to imagine why something which implements two interfaces should be excluded. Maybe if you explain some more the reason for it, it will become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my example below. If you could introduce another interface as the base type of your interfaces, this solution should work for your. Once instantiated, it will either except subtypes of `One` or subtypes of `Two`.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassesHolder<One> ones = new ClassesHolder<One>();
        ones.add(new SubOne());
        ones.add(new SubSubOne());
    }

}

interface Zero {}
interface One extends Zero {};
interface Two extends Zero {};
class SubOne implements One {};
class SubSubOne implements One {};
class SubTwo implements Two {};
class SubSubTwo implements Two {};

class ClassesHolder<V extends Zero> {
    public <T extends V> void add(T item) {}
}
```

Comment: Harmlezz, Thanks for your answer. The example given by you accepts both SubOne and SubTwo to add. But i dont want to do that. First if you add SubOne then next you should be able to add only SubSubOne. Basically it should allow to add only one interface implementations not both.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily exclude classes that implement a particular interface. If your contract requirement references `SubOneInterface`, then it'll accept classes that implement `SubOneInterface`, regardless of what else they implement.

Trying to do otherwise seems like a bad design. If your `ClassesHolder` contains a class implementing `SubOneInterface`, then that's how it will refer to that class, and any other functionality will be hidden, due to the additional interfaces not being referenced.

You could inspect your classes upon addition to th elist e.g.

```
public void addToListOfOnes(final SubOneInterface obj) {
   if (obj instanceof SubTwoInterface) {
      // throw an exception
   } 
}
```

but that seems very poor/counterintuitive. I would take a step back and look at your design again.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Class.isInterface()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29) you can check if it belongs to a particular interface.
As per your requirement you want to check before adding to a list you are trying to check if a class is an Interface of SubOneInterface or SubTwoInterface But not mix of both interfaces.

Does that make sense?